# How To Watermark Audio

Tags: uploads, media-library, the-content, content, audio

Does anyone know a way or plugin that will help me to automatically watermark any audio uploaded in the wordpress media library

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible. Watermarking the audio with an audio editing software takes a process that 'WordPress' cannot simulate. It's advisable you do the watermarking before the audio file is uploaded.

Comment: It can be done with PHP but I really would not recommend it. If the OP has command-line access, this might be fairly simple (for an advanced user).